# Where can I find an undetectable VPN?

Tags: vpn, proxy

I don't care about if my ISP knows im using a VPN, but I need a VPN that wont be flagged or detected by any of the growing blacklists of known VPN provider IP addresses.

Obviously this is a difficult proposition, as the lists are constantly updated, so I'm wondering what my best chance would be in terms of how to go about finding a non-flagged vpn. Should I try with the small/obscure providers that might have flown under the radar?

Or is there a more permanent/custom way to get VPN IPs that wont be detected? (Im willing to pay decent money for such a service).

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Host-Your-Own-Virtual-Private-Network-VPN-with-O/

Comment: Potentially, use Tor?

Comment: This website is for asking for software. Asking for services is off-topic. Cheers! https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic

Comment: Additionally see: [Are questions for service providers welcome at our site?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a Linode, Amazon EC2 instance, etc. and set up your own VPN software using OpenVPN or similar.

**Note**: Linode gives you a single static IP, for $1/month you can get a second... with its own gateway, etc. So you'd just need to change network configuration.

Answer (score -2):

Get a small VPN.

There are thousands of vpn providers, all having tens of server. While well known VPN are likely to be blacklisted, smaller one less

Go to google, search "vpn per month" and go to pages 10 to 20 and you can find little known vpn

Comment: On the other hand, larger VPNs will have more money keep constantly changing IP addresses